# Internationalization with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization

I'm trying to solve a Internationalization problem with CakePHP but I cant get cake to start localizing... even though I have everything set up as the documentation requires... my problem is twofold:

first I'd like cake to localize all __(''); strings I defined in the views. The second thing is that I have a datetime input field which I'd like to localize as well...
currently my Locale folder looks as follows:

```
/Locale
-cake_dev.pot
-cake.pot
-default.pot
-/DE/LC_MESSAGES/
--default.pot
```

and in my /config/bootstrap.php the last line is:

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'DE');
```

thx so much for your support!

Comment: You should provide some code

Comment: It is always a good idea to consult documentation first or see how other code/plugins handle it, e.g. https://github.com/cakephp/localized/tree/master/Locale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it should be `deu`. And you need rename `deu/LC_MESSAGES/default.pot` to `deu/LC_MESSAGES/default.po`, open it in poedit, update it (catalog) from `default.pot` and translate it. On save `deu/LC_MESSAGES/default.mo` will be compiled, this file is used by cake.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Cake internally converts DE to DEU, further it should be lower cased. Systems other than windows are case sensitive. So try "deu" instead of "DE".